# Hit Action Result on another domain

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services

i am trying to hit on some other IP using POST method 
 
      $(document).ready(function () {

```
    var json = {"data": "parminder" };

    $.ajax(
  {
   type: "POST",
    url: "http://someip/webservice/getdata",
  data: JSON.stringify(json),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "JSONP",
      async: false,
      complete: cmp,
      error: OnError

  });
    function cmp(data) {

        alert("yourdata    " + data.responseText)
    };

    function OnError(msg) {
        alert('error = ' + msg.d);
    }




  });
    </script>
```

**butbn giving me error of 404  not found .Please help me.It is working with query string**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getdata(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                devicedata obj = new devicedata() { data = data };
                database.devicedatas.Add(obj);
                database.SaveChanges();
                return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //return "success" ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json("Fail", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //return "Fail" ;
            }

        }
```

**i am trying to access   actionresult as webservice .it return success when using get method  to hit actionresult   but it giving error  (404) not found  when using post method to hit actionresult**

Comment: are you able to access URL in browser?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your_ip | *` needs to to be enabled on the server

Comment: YES  when using  get request

Comment: Well..`access-control-allow-methods` needs to dictate post, too.

Comment: please  can u tell where can i add this code Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your_ip | *

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need to allow standard cross origin resource sharing. Place it in your .htaccess file on the server.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpGetAttribute` instructs the MVC framework to only allow GET requests. If you want to also allow POST actions, you have to remove the attribute.

Comment: friends i have tried a lot things my problem is solved by just removing  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",